# How to create a DSL in Elisp

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

I want to create a DSL in Elisp looking something like this:

```
(install
 ;; do install
 )

(uninstall
 ;; do uninstall
 )
```

However, since Elisp have a global namespace, this is not a good idea. And prefixing the functions like this, is so darn ugly.

```
(package-install
 ;; do install
 )

(package-uninstall
 ;; do uninstall
 )
```

So I thought as a compromise all commands could be wrapped in a commands call like this:

```
(commands
 (install
  ;; do install
  )

 (uninstall
  ;; do uninstall
  )

 ;; ...
 )
```

But since I don't want **install** and **uninstall** in the global namespace, I somehow have to in the commands macro, replace all occurrences of the commands with maybe for example the prefix names, like this:

```
(defmacro commands (&rest body)
  (mapcar
   (lambda (exp)
     (setcar exp (intern (concat "package-" (symbol-name (car exp)))))
     (setcdr exp (list (cons 'progn (cdr exp)))))
   body)
  `(progn ,@body))

(commands
 (install
  ;; do install
  )

 (uninstall
  ;; do uninstall
  )

 ;; ...
 )
```

This seems like such a hack. Plus it will not work if there are any nested commands.

Is there any good solution for this or is hack the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: YASnipper prefixes their functions with `yas/`, so you get `yas/expand` and so on. I didn't think that was ugly at all. I adopted the convention for the tfs integration I wrote, so there is `tfs/checkout`, `tfs/add`, and so on. This seems a cheap-and-easy way to do name scoping, in the absence of formal support for it.

Comment: Just a stylistic annotation: I wouldn't use `setcar`/`setcdr` as you do in the definition of the `command` macro. Create a fresh `cons` (which would even make the code cleaner). You don't know, what effects it might have, if your macro expander arbitrarily modifies the original code tree in a destructive way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about locally defining `install` and friends? This won't hide standard functions, but it doesn't look like that's what you're really after.

```
(defmacro commands (&rest body)
  `(flet ((install (&rest args) (apply 'package-install args))
          (uninstall (&rest args) (apply 'package-uninstall args)))
     ,@body))
```

Of course you'd want to generate that list of `flet` arguments automatically. You do need a list of your package's elements somewhere, possibly using `(feature-symbols 'package)`.